Not able to create 2GP managed package with Commerce Cloud & OMS
We are building a 2GP managed package and our package is an extension for both SFCC and OMS. I have created a scratch org and enabled both Commerce Cloud and Order Management System. Also we have written some apex classes which are referencing these objects from SFCC and OMS

OrderSummary
OrderItemSummary
FulfillmentOrder
FulfillmentOrderLineItem
SalesChannel
etc.

Also, referencing some standard events like FOStatusChangedEvent, OrderSummaryCreatedEvent, etc.
Everything is working in the scratch org as expected.
But when we are trying to create a new package version, running into these errors
Invalid Type: OrderSummary
Invalid Type: OrderItemSummary
Invalid Type: FulfillmentOrder
Invalid Type: FulfillmentOrderLineItem
Invalid Type: SalesChannel

We have tried to update the scratch org definition and added these settings.
{
  "orgName": "My Test Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "orderManagementSettings": {
      "enableOrderManagement": true
    },
    "orderSettings": {
      "enableEnhancedCommerceOrders" : true,
      "enableNegativeQuantity" : true,
      "enableOptionalPricebook" : true,
      "enableOrderEvents" : true,
      "enableOrderWithMultiplePriceBooks" : true,
      "enableOrders" : true,
      "enableReductionOrders" : true,
      "enableZeroQuantity" : true
    },
    "commerceSettings": {
      "commerceAppEnabled": true,
      "commerceDiscoveryExpansion": true,
      "commerceEnabled": true,
      "lowestUnitPriceTracking": true,
      "enableOrderEvents" : true
    },
    "eventSettings": {
      "enableStreamingApi": true
    }
  },
  "hasSampleData": true
}

Not able to figure out what settings we need to enable to be able to create the package version successfully.
